# Dynamic UITableViewCell with insertRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to design a UITableView where I need to insert a row whose height (custom UITableViewCell height) will be decided depending on the length of its UILabel string.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout) from Ray Wenderlich to adjust uitableview cell height with respect to its UILabel height. But when I use insertRowAtIndexPath to insert a row using custom UITableViewCell,

```
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sizingCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:RWBasicCellIdentifier];
  });
```

will make sure that a row will be inserted only once and not multiple times.

How to insertRowAtIndexPath of variable height?

Here's my heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
ChattingCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChattingCellId2"];
        CGRect messageLabelRect = [cell.labelMessage.attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){cell.labelMessage.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX} options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
        cell.labelMessage.frame = CGRectMake(cell.labelMessage.frame.origin.x, cell.labelMessage.frame.origin.y, cell.labelMessage.frame.size.width, messageLabelRect.size.height);
        [cell.labelMessage sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(cell.labelMessage.frame.size.width, messageLabelRect.size.height)];
        float height = cell.labelMessage.frame.origin.y + cell.labelMessage.frame.size.height + cell.labelSent.frame.size.height + 10;
        [cell prepareForReuse]; //here your cell would normally be returned for cellForRowAtIndexPath, except we just mark it for reuse, we have the height we need
        return height;
```

Comment: What does the posted code have to do with your question? Using `insertRowAtIndexPath` is irrelevant to your question. Implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. That will handle any row, not matter how it is added to the table.

Comment: I understand that @rmaddy .. I am aware of datasource and delegate methods.. but how to change UITableViewHeight only for one cell using heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I mean uitableviewcell height

Comment: `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is used for all rows, not just one. Base your calculation off of the data for the given index path.

Comment: @rmaddy I added my heightForRowAtIndexPath code in my question

Answer (score 1):

You should also implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` in table view controller.
When you call `insertRowAtIndexPath`, first the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called, then the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
In `heightForRowAtIndexPath` you must determine height of the new cell, assume that you are using auto layout, so you can set the
`frame.size.width` of the cell and force to layout the cell by calling `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded`, then you have height computed by auto layout.